# different results based on type.measure argument in cv.glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I have a training matrix 30660 x 1612 consisting of 3 dense continuous features and the remaining sparse binary features.  #cases (1): 6132,   #controls (0): 24528.

```
model.glmnet <- cv.glmnet(matrix.glmnet, factor(obs.dt[,iscase]), family='binomial', type.measure='class', nfolds=5)
plot(model.glmnet)
```

When `type.measure='class'`, I get
[image]

When `type.measure='auc'`, I get
[image]

The coefficients selected using `coef(model.glmnet, s='lambda.1se')`, where `model.glmnet` was created with `type.measure='auc'` make perfect sense!  Question: why are the results so different?  Any thoughts on what the data characteristics may be to lead to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar observation. The effective lambda is different for type.measure='auc' and type.measure='class' even after increasing the nfolds and using the same seed in set.seed().

Comment: You're using different metrics to decide what the optimal lambda value it; of course you get different results.